# iOS automation if cell contains then tap

Tags: ios, for-loop, automation, contains

I'm trying to figure out if a cell contains a certain month, then tap it using iOS automation. Here is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i <1000; i++)
{ 
    var monthNames = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

    var a = new Date();
    var b = a.getMonth();
    var c = monthNames[b+1];


    if (app.mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[i].name().contains(c))
    {
        (target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[i].tap());  
    }
    else     
    {
   /*continue*/
    }
}
```

I keep getting errors saying `if (app.mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[i].name().contains(c))` is undefined or contains is not a set variable depending on how I try to use contains.

I also know the month name is available in the cell.